# Ubuntu Restrict a user to a certain folder

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp, sftp

Is it possible to only allow a user to connect to my server using FTP/SFTP and they can only access a certain folder for example /var/www/ftp, inside that folder there might be links to other folders but the user does not have full access to the server. I have tried using this tutorial by DigitalOcean [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-restrict-a-user-to-a-specific-directory) but it does not work for me.

Thanks

Comment: (This post should not have been upvoted, but I did it to correct what I feel is an overzealous downvote).  You should advise what happened with the DigitalOcean tutorial.  It would also be good to know what FTP server you used.

Comment: Rather then following the tutorial you used, you might want to focus on an FTP based solution based on pureftp - Something like https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PureFTP should guide you through what you are trying to do.

Comment: @davidgo with that tutorial can I make a user group then have different users in that group that have access to different folders?

Comment: Also when I try to use the PureFTP and open the pureadmin I get an error `(pureadmin:24771): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:` Know why?

Comment: @HarryCaneron Your error with PureAdmin (which I've never used) may be because you are not in an X window, or you have changed users and lost the X display export settings - but I fear you need to engage an expert as I get the impression you are going to be exposing this to the Internet and you need more knowledge then SU can really provide.